# Change opacity of grid at runtime in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, opacity

I want to change the opacity of the background of a grid in my Windows 8 app.

```
grid1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xA9, 0xAB, 0xAC));                    
grid1.Background.Opacity = 10;
```

I want to make this color transparent. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is obvious, opacity is a double range from 0 (transparent) to 1 (opaque). 10 > 1 so it is opaque. I guess you meant :

```
grid1.Background.Opacity = 0.1;
```